# How to create multiple table columns in 1 room database?

Tags: android, database, kotlin

I have created 1 room database following best practices in kotlin. I want to create 2 table columns within 1 database. How can I stack tables within the database? Any advice is appreciated!

Something similar to this:
https://gyazo.com/6327f163f463a4b19b59c5aece2136e3

Age database: https://gyazo.com/0074f2e4f002de9a3ad07ec593a826d4

Gender database: https://gyazo.com/c8b800b8f2f4fc6b43a9de2ddfdb1e7d

My age database:

```
@Database(entities = [Age::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class AgeDb : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun AgeDao() : AgeDao

    companion object {

        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE : AgeDb? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context) : AgeDb {

            val tempInstance = INSTANCE
            if (tempInstance != null) {

                return tempInstance
            }

            synchronized(this) {

                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    AgeDb::class.java,
                    "dropdown_age"
                ).build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Best practice is to create separate TABLES, not DATABASES.

Comment: ahhh I see, but is there a way to structure databases so that tables are one beneath the other ? I know all information can be put into an online database such as firebase firestore and structured. Is this possible in a local database then as well ? @Agent_L

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "beneath". Tables don't have a hierarchy, unless you create one with foreign keys. As a rule of thumb, you can do everything with local database.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of creating a  sort of heirarchy. Something similar to this,: https://gyazo.com/6327f163f463a4b19b59c5aece2136e3. This way I can have 2 tables of data in 1 database - one beneath the other. How can I do this ?

Comment: Will re-frame the question!

Answer (score 1):

i see your code. actually,I can't understand why don't you use only one database? and create two table ,even you can only create one table to save age attribute and gender attribute. so,maybe you would think about it, did you design the right databases and tabels

Comment: @Roony luo yes that is a possibility, but I am more focused on combining 2 databases. Lets say I have 1 database with 5 attributes ( name, age etc. ) and another database with 5 attributes ( ex. favourit foods ). Instead of having 1 database to occupy all of these 10 attributes, I can have 2 seperate databases combined into 1. One after another with 5 on top row and 5 on bottom row. It feels more convenient this way!